# MDX query - Subselect implementation - Select all values of a column except one

Tags: mdx

I have to implement a query with the following requirements.

1) I need to have multiple conditions(with AND,OR).
2) There are conditions where I need to exclude the records with a particular value.

```
SELECT {...} ON Columns, {...} ON ROWS
FROM
  (SELECT {([Element1].[Value].&[98]&[002], [Element2].Value.&[Value1]), 
           ([Element1].[Value].&[98]&[004], [Element2].Value.&[Value2]),                                        ([Element1].[Value].&[98]&[005], [Element2].Value.NOTIN[value1, value2]), } ON    Columns
FROM [CubeName])
```

I have mentioned NOTIN[value1,value2]) as I am unaware of how this can be implemented. I have to get all values except those mentioned. Please let me know if any one can provide a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would generally use the function `EXCEPT` to exclude some members from a set:

```
SELECT 
  {...} ON 0
, {...} ON 1
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      EXCEPT(
        [Element1].[Value].[Value].MEMBERS    //<<name of the full set
       ,{    //<<the set to be excluded
          [Element1].[Value].&[98]&[002], 
          [Element1].[Value].&[98]&[004], 
          [Element1].[Value].&[98]&[005]
        } ON    0
     FROM [CubeName]
  );
```

The above could be expanded out to tuples but the first argument will need to be a cross-join:

```
SELECT 
  {...} ON 0
, {...} ON 1
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      EXCEPT(
         [Element1].[Hier1].[Hier1].MEMBERS 
       * [Element1].[Hier2].[Hier2].MEMBERS   //<<name of the full set
       ,{    //<<the set to be excluded
          ([Element1].[Hier1].[Hier1].&[Value1],[Element1].[Hier2].[Hier2].&[Value1]), 
          ([Element1].[Hier1].[Hier1].&[Value2],[Element1].[Hier2].[Hier2].&[Value2]), 
          ([Element1].[Hier1].[Hier1].&[Value3],[Element1].[Hier2].[Hier2].&[Value3]),
        } ON    0
     FROM [CubeName]
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance . That worked. Appreciate your help.

Comment: That was useful. Could you help me add the except inside ANDs and ORs.

Comment: Like the one here  - SELECT {[Ele1].[Value].&[1000] AND ( [Ele2].[Value].&[20] OR [Ele3].[Value].&[200]) AND [Ele4].[Value].NOT[15] AND ([Ele5].[Value].&[10] OR [Ele6].[Value].NOINT[100, 200])} ON COLUMNS FROM [CubeName]

Comment: A set is effectively AND ...no need for the word AND just put the two members in between curly braces `{...}`. Please add this AND / OR problem as a new question